# trying to run a .bat that runs an .exe from a mapped drive or share and have file not found

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have a file share called `fileser01`. I placed my exe which is hp.exe in `\\fileser01\\software`. I can map a drive whith this command:

```
net use f: \\fileser01\\software /user:domain\myaccount
```

So the drive shows as `f:`.

In the .bat file I have `start "f:\" hp.exe` but it says it can't find the file. What am I doing wrong? I even try to run a vbs and it says it can't find the file

I tried `"f:"` I tried putting it in another folder in software like media so `"f:\media"` and still same problem.

Comment: You should be able to call it with just `f:\hp.exe`, or `call f:\hp.exe`.

Comment: Are you able to navigate to the drive after your net use command?

Answer (score 1):

Your question says your batch files contains this:

```
start "f:\" hp.exe
```

No, that will not work.  It needs to be this:

```
 start "Window Title" "f:\hp.exe"
```

Or this:

```
 start f:\hp.exe
```

The entire file name with no added spaces needs to be contained between the quotation marks.  And in this case you could even omit the quotation marks since the file name and path contain no spaces, in which case you can also omit the window title.

Comment: That still will not work because START treats the first quoted parameter as a title for the window. It would work if you removed the quotes: `start f:\hp.exe`. Or if you want to preserve the quotes, then you need to specify a title - empty is OK: `start "" "f:\hp.exe"`